# Twisted and connection to SQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server, twisted

I have a Twisted application that runs in an x86 64bit machine with Win 2008 server.

It needs to be connected to a SQL Server database that runs in another machine (in a cloud actually but I have IP, port, db name, credentials).

Do I need to install anything more that Twisted to my machine?

And which API should be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[twisted.enterprise.adbapi](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/rdbms.html) will help you use any [DB-API 2.0](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) module without blocking.  It gives you a non-blocking, Deferred-based API by running database operations in a thread pool.  [python-mssql](http://pymssql.sourceforge.net/) appears to be a DB-API 2.0 compliant module for MSSQL (I've never used it myself though).

Comment: Thank you. I will try to use python-mssql.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have portable mssql server library, you can try the module from www.pytds.com.
It works with 2.5+ and 3.1, have a good stored procedure support. It's api is more "functional", and has some good features you won't find anywhere else.